# Add a new node to existing datastax cluster on google cloud

Tags: cassandra, google-cloud-platform, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I have deployed 9 node Datastax Cluster on google cloud. Now want to add one more node to one of the Data Center.

How to create a new node from existing one instead of installing datastax manually and adding to cluster.

I want to create a node from the existing node( like image copy or something else not sure exactly).

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the documentation: [adding nodes to an existing cluster](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/ops_add_node_to_cluster_t.html). You can clone a disk to save you the server installation BUT 1/ don't let cassandra start when you boot your new node and 2/ wipe all the cassandra data on this node.

If you clone a disk  / rsync `/var/lib/cassandra` / etc and start a new node, it will use its host id... which already exists in your cluster (it's the one from the host you copied). Then, bad things happen.